# H driver circuit for 6000 V, ~0 A

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, high-voltage

I want to make an H driver to switch a very high voltage (e.g. 6000 V), but close to 0 A as almost no current is flowing (<1 mA) in either direction.

I'm having trouble finding transistors that can handle this. It only needs to switch at about 0.1 Hz; could be done manually even. What other components could I do this with?

Comment: An 11 kV vacuum contactor springs to mind but you'll have to check its DC voltage rating because AC self-extinguishes sparks cyclically.

Comment: I've no answer but you need to include the current.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat have added - basically 0A or close to

Comment: How close to 0 amps? Numbers please.

Comment: @Andyaka I said <1mA above - unlikely to get that high, but should be able to cope with that in the eventuality I suppose

Comment: So, electrostatic? Transistors must be cascoded (wired in series), there aren't transistors commercially available at quite that voltage. If switching doesn't need to be fast at all, how about two power supplies in series, opposite polarity, and just switch on one or the other?

Comment: @TimWilliams Good point! Visited a HV-DC/DC substation once....Huge arrays and tons of banks of in-series switches. Really fascinating!

Comment: The issue with stacked switches is, that the last one that closes, sees the full voltage, so they either need sufficient avalanche rating or some other means of guaranteeing zero timing skew. The contactor sound good

Comment: It probably doesn't need to be a H-bridge if you can live with maybe 10 watts power dissipation in the control circuit (given that the current is so puny).

Comment: @tobalt Hmm, let's see. Probably since load current is minimal, capacitance dominates, so one side turns off, and its voltage hardly changes; then the other side turns on and rams voltage across the one side. That is, hard-switching commutation. Voltage distribution can then be solved by 1. using a capacitive divider to enforce even voltage distribution along the one stack, and 2. Miller effect to enforce a fixed dV/dt turn-on for each device in the chain. Peak current can also be limited, minimizing transient effects. A surprisingly analog solution to a seemingly digital problem. :)